# Using simple primaryKey & ForeighKey in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

### I am trying to build a relationship Schema in MySQL

---

**My Objective for Design**::

Using `TABLE-1` to access the value of `TABLE-2` & `TABLE-3`

---

**My present Design**::

[image]

---

**My Question**::

1. Is my DESIGN a vaild one ?
2. Have i used proper key's in proper locations & pointed to right
   values ?
3. What sql concepts should i need to learn ( using .... AS, JOIN, etc) to
   achieve this

---

### {EDIT} --- Have improved naming conventions

[image]

*Please be easy with answers, I am a newbie*

Comment: Your design isn't a valid one at least because horrible naming for your attributes

Comment: @ Alma Do ..... Naming conventions i have simply taken for example .... is it not possible Using TABLE-1 to access the value of TABLE-2 & TABLE-3 .... with my present design

Comment: Then post your _actual_ scheme since having attributes with same names isn't valid in database design

Comment: @ Alma Do ..... Please see the update .... i have improved the naming conventions for better design

Comment: Your design seems valid but does it meet your requirements? Are those relations 1-to-Many or 0/1-to-Many? What are the table names and fields in your specification, what exactly are you going to need?

Comment: @ Zefnus .... At present i have built one-to-one relationship from table-1 to table-3 ...... then table 2 to table-4 has many to many relationship .... any inputs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ok, it's like a puzzle now. Ignoring all naming convention and your requirements.. your design is valid assuming your only consideration is to see if you will be able to do the `JOIN` operations you'll need. You'll be able to `JOIN` *Table1* and *Table3* `ON` Table3PK and then that *Table3* with *Table2* and *Table4* `ON` Table2PK and Table4PK

Solving the puzzle part is a bit hard. I couldn't figure out what exactly you are trying to achieve. I'm assuming:

> Table4 is the *definition* table for **Teachers**
>
> Table2 is the *definition* table for **Stundents**
>
> Table3 is the table that *matches* **Students** with **Teachers** (Many-to-Many relation Many students can relate with many teachers)
>
> Table1 is ??? (i hope you are not planning to use this table as *definition* table for **Courses**)

So, my answer to your questions:

> 1) Legal, seems valid but depends on your specification
>
> 2) Yes
>
> 3) *INNER JOIN*, *RIGHT JOIN* and *LEFT JOIN* if you have any nullable foreign key fields